# Can I use Jio SIM in the second slot of my Redmi 3s Prime phone?

Tags: lock-screens

Can I use Jio SIM in the second slot of my Redmi 3s Prime phone? The second SIM slot is a nano type SIM slot. Please clear my doubt as soon as you can.

Comment: Define 'use'. Since your phone does not support voLTE, you have to use Reliance app Jio4GVoice to make phone calls using your Jio SIM. Of course for Internet connectivity you dont need this app.

Answer (score 1):

Not all dual SIM phones have 4G + 4G support.
It is mostly 4G + 2G(or sometimes 3G).

It is not predetermined which SIM slot will be able to use the 4G bands and which won't.

Usually when a dual SIM phone is booted for the first time with two SIM cards, on the setup screen it asks the user to select which SIM card would be used for mobile data. Whichever is selected becomes the primary data SIM slot and is subsequently used for 4G LTE or 3G whichever the phone supports. The second slot in most phones either cannot use data or even if it does, cannot use the 4G or 3G bands- whichever the phone supports and the first SIM slot can use.
In case of hybrid dual SIM phones with single SIM does not arise as there is only one SIM card in use, and the device will automatically use whichever SIM slot is occupied as it's primary data SIM and will switch to 4G if available.
There is no official confirmation of Redmi 3S Prime being a 4G + 4G phone. Seeing how it is a budget phone, it is most likely 4G + 3G/2G.
If you are booting the device for the first time after inserting both the SIM cards (doesn't matter if Jio SIM is in second SIM slot, you can select the Jio SIM when prompted to select which SIM you want to use for data and it'll work.
If you inserted the Jio SIM in the second slot after having already booted the device, it probably won't work. What you have to do in this case is reset the phone, and when you see the setup screen, select the slot in which you have put the Jio SIM, and you'll be good to go.

Answer (score 0):

Jio4GVoice app automatically reads the first SIM slot.So put the Jio Sim in the first slot if you are using an LTE device. If you are using a voLTE device, you can use either of the SIM slots.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen in some internet videos that jio works in second sim slot of redmi 3s after changing certain network and access point settings. But in some videos,internet is working but calling is not possible. When i tried on my own redmi 3s, I too could not get a volte sign and so could not make a call. However,we can install jio4gvoice app and call using that app without any problem.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use on sim slot 2, only if it supports 4G too.  I am now using in my second slot in my Galaxy E5 4G mobile.